# What's the difference between Cordova and Windows 10 Javascript Apps?

Tags: javascript, cordova, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, universal

In Visual Studio 2015 I go:
New Project -> Under Javascript/Windows -> Blank App (Universal Windows)

It then creates a new app that has an .html file, a .js, .css, etc.
I then can access system level things via an object that's exposed to javascript.

Now in order of Microsoft to have implemented this I'm guessing my app is hosted within a webview of some sort.

Now let's take Cordova (or Phonegap), I create a windows cordova app and this is a windows app that has a hosted WebView within it. (or does it? atleast that's what it does in iOS and Android).

So isn't this redundant? If my app itself can be a WebView (by making a javascript windows 10 app). Why would I want to host ANOTHER webview like cordova?

Or maybe I'm not understanding something..

Comment: In short, Javascript UWP app is native, the same as C#/XAML apps; Windows Cordova is cross-platform web-based app.

Comment: I mean within the context of windows.

Comment: windows javascript apps and cordova apps on windows use the same webview, the only difference between a cordova app and a windows 10 app is the code you use for using native things on cordova apps will work on ios and android too (if you use a cordova plugin), but the code you use for using native things on a windows 10 app won't work on cordova apps. Most cordova plugins for windows 10 just wrap the javascript code a windows 10 app uses to call native code, but keeps the same javascript API as other platforms.

Comment: I don't think windows javascript apps use a webview, I think it's built into the operating system. it's probably using the edge rendering library internally. but there's no notion of creating a webview when you create a javascript app. atleast I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 Javascript Apps (Also known as [WinJS](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/winjs)) is a way of building native Windows apps with web based technologies. WinJS provides libraries that provide direct access to the device, underlying OS and framework.

Cordova apps are also built with web based technologies and run inside an embedded web view. Cordova provides a set of libraries for accessing details on the device but these go through another layer that is specific to the OS. While WinJS is only for Windows apps, Cordova apps can, for the most part, be easily rebuilt to run on different platforms.